How to make this conversion from a binary integer linear program to a quadratic program?
I saw a conversion from a binary integer linear program (BLP) to a quadratic program (QP) in this link https://qr.ae/psu9Wr. I will repeat the problem below. The original problem is
\begin{align}
    \max &&3x_1+2x_2-x_3\\
    \text{s.t.} &&x_1+x_2+x_3&\leq2,\\
&&x_1-x_2+x_3&\leq1,\\
&&x_1,x_2,x_3&\in\{0,1\}.
\end{align}
The author converts this BLP by doing four things as he described:

Rewrite the binary integer variables as continuous variables bounded between 0 and 1.
Replace each binary variable $x_i$ with a new variable $y_i$ such that $y_i=x_i(1-x_i)$.
Replace each product $x_ix_j$ with a new variable $z_{ij}$ such that $z_{ij}=x_ix_j$.
Express the objective function and constraints using the new variables $y_i$ and $z_{ij}$.
Then, he got the converted problem as follows:
\begin{align}
    \max &&3y_1+2y_2-y_3\\
    \text{s.t.}&& y_1+y_2+y_3-2z_{12}-2z_{13}&\leq0,\\
&&y_1-y_2+y_3-z_{12}+z_{23}&\leq1,\\
&&y_1,y_2,y_3,z_{12},z_{13},z_{23}&\in[0,1].
\end{align}
I tried to use his four steps but I don't know how exactly this conversion is made. Could anyone please show me some details? And is this a common practical technique for BLP? If so, could you please show me some references or keywords to learn? Thank you very much!


I don't see how to obtain that reformulation nor why he calls it "convex quadratic form" instead of just LP, but it might be related to the reformulation-linearization technique (RLT), the first two steps of which are as follows.
Multiply each constraint by $x_i$ or $1-x_i$:
\begin{align}
    \max &&3x_1+2x_2-x_3\\
    \text{s.t.}
&&(x_1+x_2+x_3)x_1 &\le 2x_1,\\
&&(x_1+x_2+x_3)(1-x_1) &\le 2(1-x_1),\\
&&(x_1+x_2+x_3)x_2 &\le 2x_2,\\
&&(x_1+x_2+x_3)(1-x_2) &\le 2(1-x_2),\\
&&(x_1+x_2+x_3)x_3 &\le 2x_3,\\
&&(x_1+x_2+x_3)(1-x_3) &\le 2(1-x_3),\\
&&(x_1-x_2+x_3)x_1 &\le 1x_1,\\
&&(x_1-x_2+x_3)(1-x_1) &\le 1(1-x_1),\\
&&(x_1-x_2+x_3)x_2 &\le 1x_2,\\
&&(x_1-x_2+x_3)(1-x_2) &\le 1(1-x_2),\\
&&(x_1-x_2+x_3)x_3 &\le 1x_3,\\
&&(x_1-x_2+x_3)(1-x_3) &\le 1(1-x_3),\\
&&x_i&\in\{0,1\}.
\end{align}
Replace $x_i^2$ with $x_i$, and replace $x_ix_j$ with $z_{ij}$:
\begin{align}
    \max &&3x_1+2x_2-x_3\\
    \text{s.t.}
&&x_1+z_{12}+z_{13} &\le 2x_1,\\
&&x_2+x_3-z_{12}-z_{13} &\le 2-2x_1,\\
&&z_{12}+x_2+z_{23} &\le 2x_2,\\
&&x_1+x_3-z_{12}-z_{23} &\le 2-2x_2,\\
&&z_{13}+z_{23}+x_3 &\le 2x_3,\\
&&x_1+x_2-z_{13}-z_{23} &\le 2-2x_3,\\
&&x_1-z_{12}+z_{13} &\le x_1,\\
&&-x_2+x_3+z_{12}-z_{13} &\le 1-x_1,\\
&&z_{12}-x_2+z_{23} &\le x_2,\\
&&x_1+x_3-z_{12}-z_{23} &\le 1-x_2,\\
&&z_{13}-z_{23}+x_3 &\le x_3,\\
&&x_1-x_2-z_{13}+z_{23} &\le 1-x_3,\\
&&x_i&\in\{0,1\} \\
&&z_{ij}&\in[0,1].
\end{align}
For binary polynomial optimization problems, repeating these steps is known to yield an ideal LP formulation.  See Sherali and Adams, A Hierarchy of Relaxations between the Continuous and Convex Hull Representations for Zero-One Programming Problems, SIAM Journal on Discrete Mathematics (1990).

Thanks a lot for your correction and reply! I will take a look at this technique.
